# Studying uniform continuity.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta, uniform-continuity

The definition of uniform continuity states that a function $f$ defined over an interval $I$ is uniform continuous if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \quad\exists \delta> 0$ such that $ \forall x' , x'' \in I  : 0 < |x'-x''| < \delta  \implies |f(x')-f(x'')|<\epsilon$
Is it possible to find multiple solutions for $\delta$ while using different approaches?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah why not? If you find one I can take the half of it and have another one.

Comment: The $0 <$ in $0 < |x^\prime - x^{\prime\prime}|< \delta$ is not needed.

Comment: What you state is not a theorem, it's the _definition_ of uniform continuity. A theorem that might be called "the uniform continuity" theorem states that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then $f$ _is_ uniformly continuous.

Comment: I meant definition , my bad.

Comment: You may be interested in Fig in the part [Visualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we're after a $\delta$ such that$$|x-y|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x)-f(y)\bigr|<\varepsilon,$$if you take $\delta'$ such that $0<\delta'\leqslant\delta$, then$$|x-y|<\delta'\implies|x-y|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x)-f(y)\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$So, yes, *of course* that it is possible to have more than one $\delta$. In fact, there are *always* infinitely many $\delta$'s that will do.

Comment: What i meant by the question is : imagine we had an exercice where we have to find delta and we found : delta < epsilon/10 using the 1st method.
Using a 2nd method we found delta < epsilon/5 
Are both values acceptable ?

Comment: @Raku I understood your question. Yes, two distinct appoaches may well lead to two distinct but equally valid $\delta$'s.

Comment: Alright , glad to have been able to get this question out of my mind, Thanks for the help!